# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() always return 'anonymousUser'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I created Spring boot application with the following configuration:

- Spring boot 2.1.0.RELEASE
- OpenJdk 11

I have an `AuditConfiguration` class in my project that looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
public class AuditConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }

    class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {
        @Override
        public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
            Principal principal = 
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            return Optional.of(principal.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

and `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` always returns `anonymousUser`.

However, the following code returns the correct user name.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/history")
public class HistoryEndpoint {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String currentUserName(Principal principal) {
        return principal.getName();
    }
}
```

I need your help for resolving this issue.

Comment: Try autowire principal object instead of getting it directly from security context holder and check if issue gone.

Comment: are you setting Authentication object into spring security context?

Comment: Please show your configuration files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got authenticared user using following class. i had problem with JPA Auditing. 
@CreatedBy always saved `null`. then i tried to get authenticated user `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` using this method. that method returned `annonymousUser`.  however my issue is fixed.

```
@ManagedBean
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

public SpringSecurityAuditorAware(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    this.httpServletRequest = httpServletRequest;
}

@Override
public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal())
            .map(Principal::getName);
}
}
```